# Clear data and restart app android

Tags: android, database, android-activity

I want to clear data and restart app in my app. For this I've used the code below. However, it doesn't seem to work. Please help me out !

```
deleteDatabase(Universal.database_name);
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
startActivity(i);
```

EDIT: I see no effect and the app simply restarts with data absolutely retained !

Comment: please give us your log file...

Comment: And please define "doesn't seem to work". What happens?

Answer (score 0):

to clear app data you can use this method:

```
   public void clearApplicationData() {
        File cache = currentActivity.getCacheDir();
        File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
        if (appDir.exists()) {
            String[] children = appDir.list();
            for (String s : children) {
                if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                    deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and in addition to restart app you should use alarm manager

```
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent restartIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this.getBaseContext(), 0, new Intent(getIntent()),
                getIntent().getFlags());
        mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, restartIntent);
        System.exit(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

** This activity shows nothing; instead, it restarts the android process */

```
public class AppRestartActivity extends Activity {
    // Do not forget to add it to AndroidManifest.xml
    // <activity android:name="your.package.name.AppRestartActivity"/>
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public static void doRestart(Activity anyActivity) {
        anyActivity.startActivity(new Intent(anyActivity.getApplicationContext(), MagicAppRestart.class));
    }
}
```